# Mismatched input 'to' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'. At for loop in PineScript Array

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to develop an indicator that shows my historic trades for all the tickers in my broker.
I'm having a hard time trying to remove the Mismatched input 'to' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'.
I've checked the following code with this checker_ticker validation and works correctly.
This situation happens to me every time I'm trying to use a for loop with the array.get function to search through the array.
Any ideas how to solve?

```
//@version=5
indicator("Historic Trades", overlay=true)

// open ordr arrays
Ord_ticker = array.new_string(0) 
Ord_action = array.new_string(0)
Ord_price = array.new_float(0)
Ord_sh_qty = array.new_float(0)
Ord_exe_date = array.new_int(0)


// Orders
array.push(Ord_ticker,'AAPL')
array.push(Ord_action,'Buy')
array.push(Ord_price,161.1)
array.push(Ord_sh_qty,10)
array.push(Ord_exe_date,timestamp(2022,01,31,09,30))
array.push(Ord_ticker,'AAPL')
array.push(Ord_action,'Buy')
array.push(Ord_price,173)
array.push(Ord_sh_qty,10)
array.push(Ord_exe_date,timestamp(2022,02,24,09,30))
array.push(Ord_ticker,'AAPL')
array.push(Ord_action,'Sell')
array.push(Ord_price,157)
array.push(Ord_sh_qty,20)
array.push(Ord_exe_date,timestamp(2022,03,10,09,30))


check_date = false
check_ticker = false


for i =0 to array.size(Ord_ticker) -1
    check_date := (array.get(Ord_exe_date,i) == time ) 
    check_ticker := (array.get(Ord_ticker,i) == syminfo.ticker   // <==== adding this line results in the error
    if check_date and check_ticker  
        action = array.get(Ord_action,i) 
        shares = array.get(Ord_sh_qty,i)
        price = array.get(Ord_price,i)
        txt_lbl = str.tostring(price,'#.#') + " "+ action +" " +str.tostring(shares,'#') 
        debug2 = label.new(x=time, y=close+7, text=txt_lbl , xloc=xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.price, color=color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 100), style=label.style_label_left, textcolor=color.blue, size=size.normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a right parentheses on that line, or rather do not need a open parentheses to the left of array.get on that line

** EDIT **

```
//@version=5
indicator("Historic Trades", overlay=true)

// open ordr arrays
Ord_ticker = array.new_string(0) 
Ord_action = array.new_string(0)
Ord_price = array.new_float(0)
Ord_sh_qty = array.new_float(0)
Ord_exe_date = array.new_int(0)


// Orders
array.push(Ord_ticker,'AAPL')
array.push(Ord_action,'Buy')
array.push(Ord_price,161.1)
array.push(Ord_sh_qty,10)
array.push(Ord_exe_date,timestamp(2022,01,31,09,30))
array.push(Ord_ticker,'AAPL')
array.push(Ord_action,'Buy')
array.push(Ord_price,173)
array.push(Ord_sh_qty,10)
array.push(Ord_exe_date,timestamp(2022,02,24,09,30))
array.push(Ord_ticker,'AAPL')
array.push(Ord_action,'Sell')
array.push(Ord_price,157)
array.push(Ord_sh_qty,20)
array.push(Ord_exe_date,timestamp(2022,03,10,09,30))


check_date = false
check_ticker = false


for i =0 to array.size(Ord_ticker) -1
    check_date := array.get(Ord_exe_date,i) == time 
    check_ticker := array.get(Ord_ticker,i) == syminfo.ticker   // <==== adding this line results in the error
    if check_date and check_ticker  
        action = array.get(Ord_action,i) 
        shares = array.get(Ord_sh_qty,i)
        price = array.get(Ord_price,i)
        txt_lbl = str.tostring(price,'#.#') + " "+ action +" " +str.tostring(shares,'#') 
        debug2 = label.new(x=time, y=close+7, text=txt_lbl , xloc=xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.price, color=color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 100), style=label.style_label_left, textcolor=color.blue, size=size.normal)
```

Comment: I double checked and everything worked perfectly with your updated version. Many thanks!